# How to update django db?

Tags: django

I have problems, I don't know how to update database...

So here is my problem:
I updated my app models.py with one line *yrs = models.CharField(max_length=4)*:

```
from django.db import models

class Books(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    *yrs = models.CharField(max_length=4)*
    read = models.CharField(max_length=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + " / " + self.author + " / " + **self.yrs** + " / " + self.read + " "
```

So, but now I get error:

```
Exception Type: DatabaseError
Exception Value:    no such column: books_books.yrs
```

So, do you know how I can fix it?
Thank you ;)

Comment: Use [South Migration tool](http://south.aeracode.org/) and do a migration for your database. Following the tutorial will give you _exactly_ what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [South](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/index.html) to migrate your data.
If you don't care about your existing data, just remove your database file (in case of sqlite3), and run 
`python manage syncdb` again

South is pretty easy to use and the tutorial is giving you a lot of real examples.

If South doesnt sound appealing to you, you can also alter directly your table using `dbshell`

```
python manage.py dbshell
ALTER TABLE <appname_modelname> ADD COLUMN <column_type> DEFAULT '';
```

Comment: +1: Also if he doesn't care about data he can do `python manage.py sqlclear MyApp` before `syncdb` instead of manually finding and removing the table.

Comment: Does sql clear avoid to have to create a super user and so on, as syncdb does?

Comment: `sqlclear` drops all tables defined in `MyApp`. It does not create anything.

Comment: Correction. Actually it only prints drop statements. It should be used like that `python manage.py sqlclear MyApp | python manage.py dbshell` (at least under Linux).